# Event Monitoring API for external systems

Tags: eventlogfile, event-monitoring

I want to be able to see the log files of the SOAP/REST calls which come from third-party systems to Salesforce.

Is is possible to achieve this through Event Monitoring API?
As I researched using the *EventLogFile* object documentation, there is an attribute called *EventType* which contains the value *URI*, among others. If I would filter my query by this value, would I see what Salesforce resource was accessed from outside the organization? (Example: /services/data/v48.0/{sObjectName} or something similar)

Also, does the file content have information about the whole server response at the time the resource was requested?

Comment: Have a look at [Event Monitoring trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring), then give it a shot in your own org.

Comment: `would I see what Salesforce resource was accessed from outside the organization` YES